# Can't use Objective C framework imported within Bridging Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, fastpdfkit

Usually I am using CocoaPods (with use_frameworks!) in order to manage my frameworks, but this PDF library (FastPdfKit) does not support CocoaPods, so i added it manually in "link binary with libraries" along with its dependencies. After that I let xcode create a bridging header for me (I created a .m file, and xcode created a bridging header automatically).

I imported the header in the bridging file like this `#import <FastPdfKit/FastPdfKit.h>`, but I can't acces any method/class from my swift files... (`Use of undeclared type 'ReaderViewController'` where ReaderViewController is a subclass of UIViewController in the framework).

I've also tried importing like this `#import 'FastPdfKit.h"` still gives the same errors.

Comment: Have you tried importing ReaderViewController directly?

Comment: And please check this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

Comment: @Akaino Yep, still nothing

Comment: Did you add it to the "Embed Frameworks" Build Phase as well?

Comment: I don't have any section named "Embedded Frameworks" in Build Phase, only "Embedded Pods Frameworks"...

Answer (score 0):

To import Objective-C code into Swift from the same framework, go to `Build Settings > Packaging` and make sure the `Defines Module` setting for that framework target is set to “**Yes**”.